# Threads to deal with BLE beacons: Only one works... Why?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy

this Android App is aimed to detect two BLE Beacons, this two different UUIDs. This is a pretty interesting project, able to detect different beacons and react accordingly to this.  As far as I'm using more than one BLE beacon I try to use Threads to solve the issue, but the Thread 02 does not seem to react and...I do not know why!! So anyone have experience or any clue related to this issue?? The imports I'm using to manage beacons are:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;

public class Notification_Demo extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView prox;
    TextView notif;

    LinearLayout scanBtn;
    LinearLayout notifBtn;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_BL = 2;

    String TAG = "NotificationDemo";

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeScanner scanner;
    private ScanSettings scanSettings;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edt;
    String mUuid, dRange, mMsg, frameType;
    TextView editBtn;
    Animation animation;
    ImageView wave;
    double dist = 0.5, counter = 0;
    Thread startAnim, Start_Scan02, Start_Scan03 ;

    private Context mContext;
       
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        checkLocBT();
        inicializeBluetooth();
    }

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("iBKSDemo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.radar_rotate_anim);

        editBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
        editBtn.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));

        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAnim.interrupt();
                wave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                wave.clearAnimation();
                showSettingsDialog();
            }
        });

        wave = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.notifWave);

        loadFilter();
        Start_Scan02 = new Thread (Scan02);
        Start_Scan02.start();

        Start_Scan03 = new Thread (Scan03);
        Start_Scan03.start();

        //image animation of scan
        startAnim = new Thread(loopAnimation);
        startAnim.start();

        //init Bluetooth adapter
        initBT();
        //Start scan of bluetooth devices
        startLeScan(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        startLeScan(false);
        startAnim.interrupt();
        Start_Scan02.interrupt();
        Start_Scan03.interrupt();
        wave.clearAnimation();
    }

        private void startLeScan(boolean endis) {
        if (endis) {
            //********************
            //START THE BLE SCAN
            //********************
            //Scanning parameters FILTER / SETTINGS / RESULT CALLBACK. Filter are used to define a particular
            //device to scan for. The Callback is defined above as a method.
            scanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, mScanCallback);
        }else{
            //Stop scan
            scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        startLeScan(false);
    }

        private void initBT(){
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =  (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        //Create the scan settings
        ScanSettings.Builder scanSettingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
        //Set scan latency mode. Lower latency, faster device detection/more battery and resources consumption
        scanSettingsBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
        //Wrap settings together and save on a settings var (declared globally).
        scanSettings = scanSettingsBuilder.build();
        //Get the BLE scanner from the BT adapter (var declared globally)
        scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    }

    Thread loopAnimation = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(300);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        wave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        wave.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                });
                while(true){
                    if(counter > 0){
                        counter--;
                    }
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    };



    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

            //Convert advertising bytes to string for a easier parsing. GetBytes may return a NullPointerException. Treat it right(try/catch).
            String advertisingString = byteArrayToHex(result.getScanRecord().getBytes());
            //Print the advertising String in the LOG with other device info (ADDRESS - RSSI - ADVERTISING - NAME)
            Log.i(TAG, result.getDevice().getAddress()+" - RSSI: "+result.getRssi()+"\t - "+advertisingString+" - "+result.getDevice().getName());

            mMsg = advertisingString;
            String aux = mMsg.substring(18,58);
            mMsg = aux;

            Log.i(TAG,"UID = "+ mUuid);
            if (advertisingString.contains(mUuid.replace("-",""))) {
                if (result.getRssi() > dist) {
                    if(counter == 0){
                        counter = 5;
                        startAnim.interrupt();
                        Start_Scan02.interrupt();
                        Start_Scan03.interrupt();
                        wave.clearAnimation();
                        wave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        showDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


    public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
        for(byte b: a)
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        return sb.toString();
    }


    private void showDialog(){


        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Notification_Demo.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_notification);

        Start_Scan02.interrupt();
        Start_Scan03.interrupt();

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogMsg);
        text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf"));
        //The message introduced in settings dialog is showed in this dialog

                text.setText(mMsg);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
        dialogButton.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAnim = new Thread(loopAnimation);
                startAnim.start();

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

    /** Dialog to set the trigger conditions of notification dialog **/
    private void showSettingsDialog(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Notification_Demo.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_settings);

        TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.settTitle);
        title.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));

        TextView uuidTV = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.settUuid);
        uuidTV.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));

        final Spinner spinneruid = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinneruid);
        title.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));
        spinneruid.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(frameType));


        spinneruid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                final int ft = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        EditText uuidET = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.uuid);
                        String uid;
                        if(ft == 0) {
                            uid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-ibeacon", "00000000000000000000000000000000-0001-0001");
                        }
                        else
                            uid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-edstuid", "00000000000000000000-000000000001");

                        uuidET.setText(uid);
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //optionally do something here
            }
        });

        final EditText uuid = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.uuid);
        uuid.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"));

        uuid.setText(mUuid);

        TextView rannge = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.settRange);
        rannge.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));

        final Spinner dstt = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.distSpinner);
        if(dRange.equals("Immediate")){
            dstt.setSelection(0);
        }else if(dRange.equals("Near")){
            dstt.setSelection(1);
        }else{
            dstt.setSelection(2);
        }

        TextView msgg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.settMsg);
        msgg.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));

        final EditText msgt = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.msgg);
        msgt.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"));
        msgt.setText(mMsg);
        msgt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (null != msgt.getLayout() && msgt.getLayout().getLineCount() > 5) {
                    msgt.getText().delete(msgt.getText().length() - 1, msgt.getText().length());
                }
            }
        });

        final TextView err = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.errorMsg);
        err.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf"));

        Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        cancelButton.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAnim = new Thread(loopAnimation);
                startAnim.start();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button saveButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        saveButton.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Khand-Bold.ttf"));
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isOK=true;
                edt = mPrefs.edit();
                if(spinneruid.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
                    if (uuid.getText().length() != 42) {
                        isOK=false;
                    }
                    else
                        edt.putString("uuid-ibeacon",uuid.getText().toString());
                }else{
                    if (uuid.getText().length() != 33){
                        isOK=false;
                    }
                    else
                        edt.putString("uuid-edstuid",uuid.getText().toString());
                }

                if(isOK){
                    edt.putString("frametype", Integer.toString(spinneruid.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                    edt.putString("range", dstt.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    edt.putString("msg", msgt.getText().toString());
                    edt.commit();
                    loadFilter();
                    err.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    startAnim = new Thread(loopAnimation);
                    startAnim.start();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }else {
                    err.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    //get parameters saved on SharedPreferences
    private void loadFilter(){
        frameType = mPrefs.getString("frametype","0");

        if(frameType.equals("0"))
            mUuid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-ibeacon", "00000000000000000000000000000000-0001-0001");
        else
            mUuid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-edstuid", "00000000000000000000-000000000001");

        dRange = mPrefs.getString("range", "Immediate");
        mMsg = mPrefs.getString("msg", "Hello World from Accent Systems!");


        if(dRange.equals("Immediate")){
            dist = -38;
        }else if(dRange.equals("Near")) {
            dist = -60;
        }else if(dRange.equals("Far")){
            dist = -120;
        }
    }



private BluetoothAdapter mBTAdapter;

    private void inicializeBluetooth(){

        //Check if device does support BT by hardware
        if (!getBaseContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)) {
            //Toast shows a message on the screen for a LENGTH_SHORT period
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLUETOOTH NOT SUPPORTED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        //Check if device does support BT Low Energy by hardware. Else close the app(finish())!
        if (!getBaseContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            //Toast shows a message on the screen for a LENGTH_SHORT period
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE NOT SUPPORTED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }else {
            //If BLE is supported, get the BT adapter. Preparing for use!
            mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            //If getting the adapter returns error, close the app with error message!
            if (mBTAdapter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR GETTING BLUETOOTH ADAPTER!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }else{
                //Check if BT is enabled! This method requires BT permissions in the manifest.
                if (!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    //If it is not enabled, ask user to enable it with default BT enable dialog! BT enable response will be received in the onActivityResult method.
                    Intent enableBTintent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBTintent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_BL);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(30)
    private void checkLocBT(){
        //If Android version is M (6.0 API 23) or newer, check if it has Location permissions
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //If Location permissions are not granted for the app, ask user for it! Request response will be received in the onRequestPermissionsResult.
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        //Check if permission request response is from Location
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //User granted permissions. Setup the scan settings
                    Log.d("TAG", "coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    //User denied Location permissions. Here you could warn the user that without
                    //Location permissions the app is not able to scan for BLE devices and eventually
                    //Close the app
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //Check if the response is from BT
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_BL){
            // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    //Filtro para 02
    private void loadFilter_02(){
        frameType = mPrefs.getString("frametype","0");

        if(frameType.equals("0"))
            mUuid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-ibeacon", "00000000000000000000000000000002-0002-0002");
        else
            mUuid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-edstuid", "00000000000000000000-000000000002");

        dRange = mPrefs.getString("range", "Far");
        mMsg = mPrefs.getString("msg", "Llamada 02!!");

//        if(dRange.equals("Immediate")){
//            dist = -38;
//        }else if(dRange.equals("Near")) {
//            dist = -60;
//        }else if(dRange.equals("Far")){
            dist = -120;
    }

    //Filtro para 03
    private void loadFilter_03(){
        frameType = mPrefs.getString("frametype","0");

        if(frameType.equals("0"))
            mUuid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-ibeacon", "00000000000000000000000000000003-0003-0003");
        else
            mUuid = mPrefs.getString("uuid-edstuid", "00000000000000000000-000000000001");

        dRange = mPrefs.getString("range", "Far");
        mMsg = mPrefs.getString("msg", "Llamada 03!!");

//        if(dRange.equals("Immediate")){
//            dist = -38;
//        }else if(dRange.equals("Near")) {
//            dist = -60;
//        }else if(dRange.equals("Far")){
        dist = -120;
    }

    Thread Scan02 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(300);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadFilter_02();
                        startLeScan(true);
                    }
                });
                while(true){
                    if(counter > 0){
                        counter--;
                    }
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread Scan03 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(300);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadFilter_03();
                        startLeScan(true);
                    }
                });
                while(true){
                    if(counter > 0){
                        counter--;
                    }
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

While I'm trying to detect two BLE beacons, I've written this piece of code to do so using Threads: Scan02 and Scan03 are intented to detect IBeacon 00...02/0002/0002 and 00...03/0003/0003. But it just detects the Scan03. I think it's because Threads ared bady defined, maybe...

Comment: Why do you need threads for this? A BLE scanner without filter is able to find all devices currently advertising. Just go trough that list and do something if your beacon is in it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Note that the BLE API is totally asynchronous. This means using threads like this makes no sense at all.